# Live Money Counter Using Stripe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, html, angularjs, stripe-payments

I want to use Stripe (stripe.com) and have a live counter of how much money was donated. I think I need to access the database and pull all of the transactions from there. I read through the documentation but can't find anything to pull that information from the database.

I'd like to use JavaScript and/or AngularJS to do this. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Found the API and the 'Retrieve balance call' but I'm not sure how to do it in Angular. https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#retrieve_balance

Comment: You need a backend service for Angular to query. That service should contact Stripe, or use data collected via [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks). **Never, ever, ever expose your Stripe secret token to the frontend.**